# Echo part of an array based on key => value match

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array structured like so:

```
<?php

$orderdata = array(
  "service_type_web" => "on",
  "custid" => "A12345",
  "domain_web" => "foo.com",
  "cust_email_web" => "foo@bar.com",
  "plantype" => "dynamic",
  "platform" => "unix",
  "service_type_ssl" => "on",
  "custid" => "A23456",
  "common_name" => "foo.bar.com",
  "cust_email_ssl" => "bar@foo.com"
);

?>
```

What I need to do is find the service_type_* part of the array, then echo all of the key value pairs until it reaches the next service_type_* where the loop then breaks.

Now this would be easy enough to do with a static data set but the array can change in size and each form can change depending on different variables, which is why the service_type_* key value entry is there.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT for clarification:

I basically need so that if I need, for example, the form data for web hosting, it would find the service_type_web key and return the following:

```html
      "service_type_web" => "on",
      "custid" => "A12345",
      "domain_web" => "foo.com",
      "cust_email_web" => "foo@bar.com",
      "plantype" => "dynamic",
      "platform" => "unix",
```

...And leaves out:

```html
      "service_type_ssl" => "on",
      "custid" => "A23456",
      "common_name" => "foo.bar.com",
      "cust_email_ssl" => "bar@foo.com"
```

SECOND EDIT:

OK, I'm nearly there. I've come up with the following:

```html
$delimiter = 0;
$array_counter = 0;

foreach($orderdata as $orderkey => $ordervalue) {
 if($orderkey == "service_type_web") {
  $new_array = array_slice($orderdata, $array_counter);
  $array_counter ++;
  $delimiter = 1;
 } elseif(preg_match('/service_type_[a-z\_]+/', $orderkey)) {
  if($delimiter == 1) {
   echo $orderkey . " => " . $ordervalue . "<br />\n";
   break;
  }
 } else {
  $array_counter ++;
 }
}
```

However the break in the if statement isn't working, even though when I get it to echo the key/value pair for the current array pointer, it echos

```html
"service_type_ssl" => "on"
```

Anyone know why? Kinda stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can check "key" before you loop into it, by using [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
$orderdata = array(
  "service_type_web" => "on",
  "custid" => "A12345",
  "domain_web" => "foo.com",
  "cust_email_web" => "foo@bar.com",
  "plantype" => "dynamic",
  "platform" => "unix",
  "service_type_ssl" => "on",
  "custid" => "A23456",
  "common_name" => "foo.bar.com",
  "cust_email_ssl" => "bar@foo.com"
);

if (array_key_exists('service_type_web', $orderdata )) {
    echo "array found";
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't this conditional mean that it'll still loop through and echo the entire array if one key is found?

Comment: do you know the possible values ? like service_type_web etc.. ?

Comment: Which isn't what I was after...need to match a key and/or value, then echo the array elements until a defined key and/or value is found.

Comment: there is pre-defined function for it, you have to go the traditional way.

Comment: The keys to match are "service_type_*" where * is web, ssl, mail, etc.

Comment: Although there are different approaches to reach the goal, it depends what you choose. You can extract keys starting with "service_type_*" before looping and then loops those keys for data

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is. This answer may guide you in right direction but still you need to do some minor changes.

```
$input = array(
  "service_type_web" => "on",
  "custid" => "A12345",
  "domain_web" => "foo.com",
  "cust_email_web" => "foo@bar.com",
  "plantype" => "dynamic",
  "platform" => "unix",
  "service_type_ssl" => "on",
  "custid" => "A23456",
  "common_name" => "foo.bar.com",
  "cust_email_ssl" => "bar@foo.com"
);
function preg_grep_keys($pattern, $input, $flags = 0) {
    return array_intersect_key($input, array_flip(preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($input), $flags)));
}

$a = preg_grep_keys("/service_type_[a-z]*/", $input);
print_r($a);
```

expected output will be

```
Array ( [service_type_web] => on [service_type_ssl] => on )
```

taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php

Comment: I might not have been as specific so apologies, but I need to echo all elements, including the first service_type_*, until it gets to the next one where the loop stops.